# Tracking PDF on another site

Tags: google-analytics

An organization wants to add some of our documentation (PDFs) on their intranet. We'd like to be able to track how many people are accessing these documents. Is there a way we can track through Google Analytics or 3rd party?

Comment: Do you have legal and technical cooperation from that organisation? Collecting data from inside a third parties intranet seems problematic on many levels  (most of all from the legal point of view).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a link shortener such as bitly to link them to the pdf. Then track the clicks on that link as opens of the PDF.